# Getting random values in MATLAB Cuda for secondary output

Tags: arrays, matlab, memory-management, cuda, gpu

Problem: 
I get for two calculated Array and two expecting outputs

1. Right calculated output
2. Random numbers, old number, numbers from the other array

I'm using MATLAB R2016B and this Coda version + GPU:

```
 CUDADevice with properties:

                  Name: 'GeForce GT 525M'
                 Index: 1
     ComputeCapability: '2.1'
        SupportsDouble: 1
         DriverVersion: 8
        ToolkitVersion: 7.5000
    MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
      MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152
    MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024 1024 64]
           MaxGridSize: [65535 65535 65535]
             SIMDWidth: 32
           TotalMemory: 1.0737e+09
       AvailableMemory: 947929088
   MultiprocessorCount: 2
          ClockRateKHz: 1200000
           ComputeMode: 'Default'
  GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1
KernelExecutionTimeout: 1
      CanMapHostMemory: 1
       DeviceSupported: 1
        DeviceSelected: 1
```

I will now try to add  and subtract two different arrays using the GPU and returning it back to MATLAB.

**MATLAB code:**

```
n = 10;
as = [1,1,1];
bs = [10,10,10];

for i = 2:n+1
  as(end+1,:) = [i,i,i];
  bs(end+1,:) = [10,10,10];
end
as = as *1;

% Load the kernel
cudaFilename = 'add2.cu';
ptxFilename = ['add2.ptx'];

% Check if the files are awareable
if((exist(cudaFilename, 'file') || exist(ptxFilename, 'file')) == 2)
  error('CUDA FILES ARE NOT HERE');
end
kernel = parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel( ptxFilename, cudaFilename );

% Make sure we have sufficient blocks to cover all of the locations
kernel.ThreadBlockSize = [kernel.MaxThreadsPerBlock,1,1];
kernel.GridSize = [ceil(n/kernel.MaxThreadsPerBlock),1];

% Call the kernel
outadd = zeros(n,1, 'single' );
outminus = zeros(n,1, 'single' );
[outadd, outminus] = feval( kernel, outadd,outminus, as, bs );
```

**Cuda snippet**

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "add_wrapper.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ size_t calculateGlobalIndex() {
    // Which block are we?
    size_t const globalBlockIndex = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x;
    // Which thread are we within the block?
    size_t const localThreadIdx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * threadIdx.y;
    // How big is each block?
    size_t const threadsPerBlock = blockDim.x*blockDim.y;
    // Which thread are we overall?
    return localThreadIdx + globalBlockIndex*threadsPerBlock;
}

__global__ void addKernel(float *c, float *d, const float *a, const  float *b)
{
    int i = calculateGlobalIndex();
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    d[i] = a[i] - b[i];
}

// C = A + B
// D = A - B
void addWithCUDA(float *cpuC,float *cpuD, const float *cpuA, const float *cpuB, const size_t sz)
{   
//TODO: add error checking

// choose which GPU to run on
cudaSetDevice(0);

// allocate GPU buffers
float *gpuA, *gpuB, *gpuC, *gpuD;
cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuA, sz*sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuB, sz*sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuC, sz*sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuD, sz*sizeof(float));
cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail");

// copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers
cudaMemcpy(gpuA, cpuA, sz*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(gpuB, cpuB, sz*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

// launch kernel on the GPU with one thread per element
addKernel<<<1,sz>>>(gpuC, gpuD, gpuA, gpuB);

// wait for the kernel to finish
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

// copy output vector from GPU buffer to host memory
cudaMemcpy(cpuC, gpuC, sz*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(cpuD, gpuD, sz*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


// cleanup
cudaFree(gpuA);
cudaFree(gpuB);
cudaFree(gpuC);
cudaFree(gpuD);
}

void resetDevice()
{
    cudaDeviceReset();
}
```

`[outadd, outminus]` are two GPU array Objects in MATLAB after running the code.

`Outadd` is always correctly calculated, `outminus` is rarely correct, mostly containing a random integer or floats, zeros or even the values of `outadd` sometime.

If i swap the order of the arithmetic operations it works out for the other one so isn't 'outminus' supposed to be calculated correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems you forgot to ask a question. Questions are denoted by a question mark (?) and can receive an answer. Please [edit] your post to contain a question, because it otherwise seems a good effort!

Comment: `kernel.MaxThreadsPerBlock` is 1024.  Since `n` is 10, your kernel will launch 1 block of 1024 threads, even though you only need 10.  Those extra threads may access your arrays out-of-bounds, so you should pass `n` as a scalar parameter to the kernel, and in your kernel you should test `i` against `n`.  You might want to study this [matlab example here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/examples/illustrating-three-approaches-to-gpu-computing-the-mandelbrot-set.html).

Comment: @Robert Crovella I think I just got stuck here and I'll restart using limit threads. Thank you!

Comment: also, aren't most matlab variables `double` type?  I think you are passing `as` and `bs` as double type, but your kernel is expecting `float` (ie. `single`) type there.  Also, since you are using the PTX interface, I'm fairly certain that your CUDA file need not have any host code in it, i.e. your `addWithCUDA` function is completely extraneous/superfluous.

Comment: @Robert Crovella I just used all that Threads which index i < n and now it works! Thank you !!

Comment: I'm sure if you provided your modified working example as an answer, explaining the changes you made, it would be useful for others.  You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Robert Crovella hint that unnecessary threads might cause access errors, I simply added an limit for the Threads.

**MATLAB**

```
[outadd, outminus] = feval( kernel, outadd,outminus, as, bs, n);
```

**CUDA KERNEL METHOD**

```
__global__ void addKernel(float *c, float *d, const float *a, const float *b, const float n)
{  
    int i = calculateGlobalIndex();
    if ( i < n ){
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        d[i] = a[i] - b[i];
   }
}
```

I think it's still not the best solution because the GPU still starts all Threads even if the most shouldn't use that much resources.

After reworking it in a proper way, I'll upload it here.